# regular expressions parentheses python

Tags: python, python-re

stuck with regular expressions. There is an example text:

> '[1 | Hi {name} | Hello {name} | Good morning {name}] other text {1
> |{name}| 3| 4} OTHER {5 |{name}| 6| 7}'

It is necessary to extract from it the constructions **[1 | Hi {name} | hello {name} | Good morning {name}]** and **{1|{name}| 3| 4}** and **{5 |{name}| 6| 7}**

```
re.findall(r'\s*(\{[^(/{name})].+\})\s*', message)
```

but I can't write a regular expression that matches the requirements
expression {name} must be ignored

Comment: Would [groups](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping) work?

Comment: You  might find this useful for working on RegEx as it tests and explains patterns: https://regex101.com/

Comment: This looks like you want a parser, not a regular expression.

Comment: What do you mean "not possible to separate everything normally"?  Do you want two capture groups? And are the digits and `{name}` placeholders that may vary in your text and/or pattern? I'm unsure what you're trying to do, and what's going wrong with it.

Comment: Yes, instead of text and numbers, anything can be. The main thing is that they are in brackets and this is not {name}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so far the solution for me is

```
re.findall(r'(\{[^n].*?[^e]\})|(\[.*?\])', message)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky with regular expressions, but quite trivial with "parsing":

```
def top_level_parens(s):
    stack = []

    for n, c in enumerate(s):
        if c in '({[':
            stack.append(n)
        elif c in ')}]':
            m = stack.pop()
            if not stack:
                yield s[m:n+1]


result = list(top_level_parens(your_string))
```

Assuming parens are properly balanced, if this is not always the case, add additional checks to the "parser".

Comment: Thanks, I've considered this option before but it doesn't quite suit me. I need to check for the presence of a structure in the text and, if true, work with this structure. It is also necessary to ignore the construction {name} and therefore I chose regular expressions